# why passing a Runnable to onAnimationEnd doesn't work?

Tags: java, android

I have an animation utility on a separate class `utility.java` I have defined the class like so:

`utility.java`

```
public class utility{
    public void setAnimation(View view1, View view, Runnable doSomethingBeforeEnding){
       AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
       animation.setDuration(fadeAnimationDelay);
       new android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(android.view.animation.Animation animation) {
                            
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(android.view.animation.Animation animation) {
                           doSomethingBeforeEnding.run()  
                           
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(android.view.animation.Animation animation) {
                            
                        }
                    }
view1.startAnimation(animation);
   }
}
```

Now, from my `MainActivity` I invoke this like this:

```
public void set(View view1, View view){
    utility.setAnimation(view1, view, new Runnable(){
                                    @Override
                                    run(){
                                       view.setRotation(180);
                                     }
                                    }
}
set(someOtherView, infomationTextView); //this textview exists and reference is not null and valid
```

The alpha animation works yet the `TextView`() does not rotate.**Why does the textview not rotate? Does the runnable not capture the view?**

Comment: Animations need to run on the UI thread. By passing a runnable in this way it is probably running on a worker thread. Try replacing doSomethingBeforeEnding.run() with view.post(doSomethingBeforeEnding);

Comment: @DexterBarretto , runnable is just an interface isnt it, how it is working on a worker thread? It'd just be an abstract class with the method right? If I define a similar runnable interface myRunnable{ public void run(){}) would every instance of myRunnable also execute on a worker Thread? It should work on the main thread because this is invoked on the main thread

Comment: on top of which it doesn't even crash, if it were running on a different thread it would give a not running on the UI thread exception

Comment: You create an `AnimationListener` but you never assign it to a variable or add it to the animation. So `doSomethingBeforeEnding.run()` should never even be called as `onAnimationEnd()` ist never called

Comment: I do start the animation

Answer (score 0):

This actually runs and was an error from my observation, I think android should've universal rotation values, in my case:

I just found out the angle value taken by `view.setRotation(angle)` and `view.animate().rotate(angle)` are not the same, e.g. -90 rotates clockwise 90 in the former case but in the latter it is counterclockwise,as I was using both methods in a loop with common variable the rotation was essentially getting nullified since the angles were being added in a loop not shown in above code.